# Issues with UITablewView and IBAction sender

Tags: ios, uitableview, ibaction, sender

i have two issues that are quite the same 
1) I have a UIButton in a cell that calls a IBAction :

```
    - (IBAction)deleteFriend:(id)sender
{


CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self->table];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self->table indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
if (indexPath != nil)
   {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self->table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

        cell.alpha = 0;
    } completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
        cell.hidden = YES;
        button.hidden = YES;


    }];
}
```

So basically i would like a confirm alert before the IBAction, but here is the problem. I don't know how to pass the sender to the buttonIndex of the UIAlertView so it can make the job of this IBAction

2) Here in the code i tell the cell ( the cell in the IBAction ) to hide, but also the button that i defined in cellforRowatIndexPath :

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(272.0f, 15.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f);
[cell button];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteFriend:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

but somehow it randomly hides other button in other cells. Why the heck doesn't it just hide in one cell ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: I would like to help you, but I can't understand the description of your problem. Are these two issues? What is cell in issue two? Try to be more clear.

Comment: there are two issues : in the first it's the cell defined by the sender, and in the latter, i just define the button in cellForRowAtIndexPath, but i hide this button in my IBAction above

Comment: Is there a reason you can't programmatically use the index of the cell and manipulate the button in that cell only?

Comment: because i launch the action by a click on the button, that launches the ibaction, where i don't have the cell declared in the method

Comment: Your questions is hard to understand. Do you want an alertView to pop up when the button is pressed?

Comment: Yes, like a confrm alert. But i want to keep the sender to know what cell i clicked on in the buttonIndex method of the UIAlertView. Do you want me to re-write the whole question ?

Comment: Do you have an idea for the UIAlertView ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what to do: Create a subclass of UITableViewCell, then create a nib file of the cell, in the tableviews class you will have to add this to the viewDidLoad method

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCell" bundle:nil]; 
[[self tableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
```

Create the label, picture, button, etc, put the action method into the cells class, and have it do what ever you want it to do there

in your tableviews class, heres the code to use

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] init]; // or your custom initialization
}


cell.name.text=[myName];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: I don't use accessory, it is just a button in the ContentView

Comment: This method is used for accessoryButtons, he is using a `UIButton`, not an accessory.

Comment: Okay, Then how about making a seperate class for the cell, and have the Action method there with what ever you want @RaphMaz

Comment: Here's what to do:

Create a subclass of UITableViewCell, then create a nib file of the cell, in the tableviews class you will have to add
 UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [[self tableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

Create the label, picture, button, etc, put the action method into the cells class, and have it do what ever you want it to do there

Comment: That looks pretty good, i guess. I am not even sure to understand how to use this, but i will give it a try, thanks !

Comment: How do i create a subclass ? I can use this for the UIAlertView problem as well ?

Comment: Im not positive about alertview,, i think so, but all you have to do is go to new file, and then click the UITableViewCell and name it whatever you want, and then just do new file, new empty nib, and drag and drop a tableview cell into it, then set the reuse identifier in inspection, and set the class of the cell in the nib to be whatever you named the cells classes the step before @RaphMaz